# How to use mulitple conditions in linq C#

Tags: c#, linq

This is my Linq query.

```
    var tmp = (from oScreenDef in listScreenDefinition
                       join oSynSession in listSynSession on
                               new { c1 = oScreenDef["venueCd"], c2 = oScreenDef["screenBytNum"] }
                               equals new { c1 = oSynSession["cinemaId"], c2 = oSynSession["screenDetails"].AsBsonDocument["num"] }
                       join oSessionAreaCount in listSessionAreaCount on
                                new { c1 = oScreenDef["venueCd"] }
                                equals new { c1 = oSessionAreaCount["cinemaId"] }
                       join oPrices in listSynPrices on
                               new { c1 = oScreenDef["venueCd"], c2 = oSynSession["cinemaId"] }
                               equals new { c1 = oPrices["cinemaId"], c2 = oPrices["cinemaId"] }
                       select new { doc = oSynSession[0], oScreenDef }).ToList();
```

In That `oPrices` object has `cinemaID` which should equal to `oScreenDef["venueId"]` and  `oSynSession["cinemaId"]`.

For that i'm including two times `oPrices["cinemaId"]` as `C1` and `C2` ..

how can i avoid that and how can i improve this query.

please suggest better way..

All `listScreenDefinition`,`listSessionAreaCount`,`listSynPrices` are `List<BsonDocument>` items getting it from `mongodb` queries..

Comment: you can use `let` to assign variables in linq rather than requerying them. Perhaps that could help you?

Comment: I am new to .Net.. can u eloborate please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `let` (see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383976.aspx)) and remove the `new { c1 = ... }`. But I don't see much more optimization:

```
var tmp = (from oScreenDef in listScreenDefinition
           let oScreenDefVenueCd = oScreenDef["venueCd"]  // let clause creates a "local variable" Inside a LINQ query
           join oSynSession in listSynSession on
               new { c1 = oScreenDefVenueCd, c2 = oScreenDef["screenBytNum"] }
               equals new { c1 = oSynSession["cinemaId"], c2 = oSynSession["screenDetails"].AsBsonDocument["num"] }
           join oSessionAreaCount in listSessionAreaCount on
               oScreenDefVenueCd
               equals oSessionAreaCount["cinemaId"]
           join oPrices in listSynPrices on
               new { c1 = oScreenDefVenueCd, c2 = oSynSession["cinemaId"] }
               equals new { c1 = oPrices["cinemaId"], c2 = oPrices["cinemaId"] }
           select new { doc = oSynSession[0], oScreenDef }).ToList();
```

### Update

```
public class MyItem
{
    public SynSession Doc;
    public ScreenDef ScreenDef;

    public MyItem(SynSession doc, ScreenDef screenDef)
    {
        Doc = doc;
        ScreenDef = screenDef;
    }
}



List<MyItem> tmp = (from oScreenDef in listScreenDefinition
                    let oScreenDefVenueCd = oScreenDef["venueCd"]  // let clause creates a "local variable" Inside a LINQ query
                    join oSynSession in listSynSession on
                        new { c1 = oScreenDefVenueCd, c2 = oScreenDef["screenBytNum"] }
                        equals new { c1 = oSynSession["cinemaId"], c2 = oSynSession["screenDetails"].AsBsonDocument["num"] }
                    join oSessionAreaCount in listSessionAreaCount on
                        oScreenDefVenueCd
                        equals oSessionAreaCount["cinemaId"]
                    join oPrices in listSynPrices on
                        new { c1 = oScreenDefVenueCd, c2 = oSynSession["cinemaId"] }
                        equals new { c1 = oPrices["cinemaId"], c2 = oPrices["cinemaId"] }
                    select new MyItem(oSynSession[0], oScreenDef)).ToList();
```

rtpHarry update note: renamed Item to MyItem to match the class at the top.

Comment: Thnaks.. And one more is here i m declaring as Var.
If i want to declare as global variable and then i neeed to assign these result.
What type needs to give for this ?

Comment: You can't because you create an anonymous type. You have to define a structure and use it. (I've update my post to show you how).